# How to integrate sourcetree for gitlab

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I worked on github and integrated it to sourcetree (MAC version) for one of my project. I would like to use sourcetree for GITLAB. But I am not able to add remote of gitlab to source tree. In Repository settings, Only I can see host type as "unknown", "bitbucket", "github" & "stash". I used unknown but it won't help me.

Sourcetree Version 2.0.4 (2.0.4)

[image]

Comment: If the below answers don't help, maybe you could share the error message you get when you try to submit.

Comment: I found this article   http://jaredleonmorgan.net/2016/03/16/Using-Source-Tree-to-Access-Git-Lab.html

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This worked for me,

**Step 1:** Click on `+ New Repository`> Clone from URL

**Step 2:** In `Source URL` provide URL followed by your user name,

Example:

- GitLab Repo URL : `http://git.zaid-labs.info/zaid/iosapp.git`
- GitLab User Name : `zaid.pathan`

So final URL should be **`http://zaid.pathan@git.zaid-labs.info/zaid/iosapp.git`**

Note: `zaid.pathan@` added before git.

**Step 3:** Enjoy cloning :).

Answer (score 17):

If you have the generated SSH key for your project from GitLab you can add it to your keychain in OS X via terminal.

ssh-add -K <ssh_generated_key_file.txt>

Once executed you will be asked for the passphrase that you entered when creating the SSH key.

Once the SSH key is in the keychain you can paste the URL from GitLab into Sourcetree like you normally would to clone the project.

Comment: For me this worked fine. Was a problem with cloning repo but after adding a key to keychain was able to access the repo and all the branches. Thanks!
Use command 'ssh-add -K {your_private_key}' to get the passphrase.

Answer (score 6):

Using the *SSH URL* from *GitLab*:

**Step 1:** Generate an *SSH Key* with **default values** from *GitLab*.

*GitLab* provides the commands to generate it. Just copy them, edit the email, and paste it in the *terminal*. Using the default values is important. Else *SourceTree* will not be able to access the *SSH key* without additional configuration.

**STEP 2:** Add the *SSH key* to your *keychain* using the command `ssh-add -K`.

Open the terminal and paste the above command in it. This will add the key to your keychain.

**STEP 3:** Restart SourceTree and clone remote repo using URL.

Restarting SourceTree is needed so that SourceTree picks the new key.

[image]

**STEP 4:** Copy the SSH URL provided by GitLab.

[image]

**STEP 5:** Paste the SSH URL into the *Source URL* field of *SourceTree*.

[image]

These steps were successfully performed on Mac OS 10.13.2 using SourceTree 2.7.1.

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Sourcetree 3.x has an option to accept gitLab. See [here](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2018/08/29/sourcetree-3-0-branches-out-with-new-hosting-services/). I now use Sourcetree 3.0.15. In Settings, put your remote gitLab host and url, etc. If your existing git client version is not supported any more, the easiest way is perhaps to use Sourcetree embedded Git by Tools->Options->Git, in Git Version near the bottom, choose Embedded. A download may happen.

Comment: This actually works. A pitfall is that in the field labeled "password" the token you created on GitLab has to be put. Not the password you normally access GitLab with.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me, but only with https link in repository setting (Repository => Repository Settings). You need to change setting to:

```
URL / path: https://**********.com/username/project.git
Host Type - Stash
Host Root URL - your root URL to GitLab (example:https://**********.com/) 
Username - leave blank
```

or in some cases if you have ssh url like:

```
git@gitlab.com:USER/REPOSITORY.git
```

and your email like:

```
test@google.com
```

then this settings should be work:

```
URL / path: https://test%40google.com@gitlab.com:USER/REPOSITORY.git
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>There does not seem to be a way to set up a GitLab account within SourceTree, but</s> if you just clone a remote repo it will use your SSH key correctly.

Edit: After SourceTree 3.0 it is possible to add various non-Atlassian git accounts, including GitLab.

Comment: http://jaredleonmorgan.net/2016/03/16/Using-Source-Tree-to-Access-Git-Lab.html      I noticed that article

Comment: I can't get it to work with SSH keys. Always asks for a password.

Comment: And when I set it up as an account in SourceTree then I get errors when trying to clone from the repositories shown: `abort: repository not found`

Answer (score 0):

Those are optional settings. Leave it set as Unknown and you should be good.

Edit: If "unknown" is no longer an option, try leaving everything in that section blank.

Comment: As of SourceTree 2.0.5 "Unknown" is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, but only with ssh key and not with username and password.

After i added the ssh key to sourcetree, i changed the settings under `Tools -> Options -> SSH-Client to work with PuTTY/Plink.`

I run into trouble after i added the ssh key, because i forgot to restart sourceTree. "this is necessary so that there is an instance of ssh-agent running that SourceTree can talk to with your key loaded."
See here:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/189412/sourcetree-with-gitlab-ssh-not-working

Answer (score 0):

**As of 2023 v4.25**, you can just add your gitlab account directly via SSH

Step 1: Under Sourcetree > *Settings > Account*

Step 2: Private Token = Copy and paste from *Gitlab > Settings > Access Tokens*

Step 3: *Generate Key > Copy to Clipboard > Paste to Gitlab > Settings > SSH Keys > Add Key*

Restart SourceTree and re-enter the host and username and token, you should be able to click Save now.

[image]